# Android Tab Fragments load at same time

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am newbie at android and I try to build tab activity. It is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);


        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new A(), "A");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new B(), "B");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new C(), "C");

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
  }
}
```

At the begining of activity fragment A and B already builded but C is waiting for click C's tab. Moreover, when I change tab from C, A and B reloaded. How to load all fragment at the begining of activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setOffscreenPageLimit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

In your case: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`