# Is there a way to load all fragments in MainActivity onCreate() using NavController and NavigationUI?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity

I fill my `RecyclerViewAdapter` using `FirebaseUI`. If I click on a `Fragment` in `BottomNavigationView` for the first time, the UI freezes for a few milliseconds due to `firestore` queries etc. I'm thinking it would be good to load all fragments at once and keep the backStack.

My code in my `MainActivity.java` looks like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
```

I already saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485988/is-there-a-way-to-keep-fragment-alive-when-using-bottomnavigationview-with-new-n) but that's for keeping the fragment alive once it is loaded.

Is there any way to load all fragments at once?

Comment: Have you checked this one https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42333663

Comment: This link is not working.

Comment: Sorry. Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958733/load-all-fragments-on-app-opening

Comment: You may check this one also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333480/android-tab-fragments-load-at-same-time

Comment: I checked all of these but unfortunately they describe solutions with ```ViewPagerAdapter``` I'm using ```NavController```